# redefine local liquibase properies that are still visible in included files

Tags: xml, liquibase

Some of my tables implement concepts that need certain columns. I want to avoid having to copy the changesets for those columns to all relevant tables and would instead rather reuse a template to create the actual changesets.

Based on different ideas I found on the net I tried this:

**db/templates/0004-create-validity-period-data-template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <include file="../templates/0002-create-versioned-data-template.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />

    <changeSet author="${table.author}" id="Create ValidityPeriodData for ${table.name}" >
        <comment>Create columns of super class ValidityPeriodData for table ${table.name}</comment>
        <addColumn tableName="${table.name}" >
            <column name="valid_from" type="date" remarks="the earliest point in time when this entry is valid" />
            <column name="valid_until" type="date" remarks="the last point in time when this entry is valid" />
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**db/changelog/0017-create-credential-table.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <property name="table.name" value="login" />
    <property name="table.author" value="guess ;-)" />

    <include file="../templates/0004-create-validity-period-data-template.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />

    <changeSet author="${table.author}" id="Create Credential table">
        <addColumn tableName="${table.name}">
            <column name="login_id" type="${uuid_type}"/>
            <column name="password" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="salt" type="VARCHAR(128)"/>
        </addColumn>
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="login_id"
                                 baseTableName="${table.name}"
                                 constraintName="fk_credential_of_login"
                                 onDelete="RESTRICT"
                                 onUpdate="RESTRICT"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="login"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**The Problem**

The properties (table.name, table.author) are by default `global="true"`, which means they are visible in all changeset files, but they can not be overwritten/redefined. So this only works for a single table, which defeats the purpose.
If I declare them as `global="false"` I can redefine them for every table that needs those columns, however now the included files do not see those properties.

**The Question**

Is there a way to redefine or overwrite properties for different changeset files (like what `global="false"` does) but still have them behave like `global="true"` in included files even recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

I had a look at the source code of liquibase. It turns out the current implementation (in versions 3.6.2, 3.6.3, 3.8.0) works a bit strange.

```
private ChangeLogParameter findParameter(String key, DatabaseChangeLog changeLog) {
    ChangeLogParameter result = null;

    List<ChangeLogParameter> found = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ChangeLogParameter param : changeLogParameters) {
        if (param.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(key) && param.isValid()) {
            found.add(param);
        }
    }
    
    if (found.size() == 1) {
        // this case is typically a global param, but could also be a unique non-global param in one specific
        // changelog
        result = found.get(0);
    } else if (found.size() > 1) {
        for (ChangeLogParameter changeLogParameter : found) {
            if (changeLogParameter.getChangeLog().equals(changeLog)) {
                result = changeLogParameter;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

You also need to know that expressions get expanded as soon as a changeSet is parsed. Parameters defined in changeSets which have not been read yet, can not be considered.

So the first time a parameter is encountered, it is in effect treated, as if it was `global=true` no matter if that's the case or not.

A second global parameter with the same name will not be recorded. However a second local parameter will be recorded.

Once the parameter list contains a second ChangeLogParameter with the same name, those will be expanded differently. Now it looks for the last defined version of that parameter defined in the same changeset file - but again not matter if it global or local.

---

**Answer**

So to answer my own question. The current implementation of  liquibase does not support that kind of thing. On top of that it behaves somewhat inconsistent in regards to expanding expressions.

---

**Solution?**

I filed a bug report with liquibase [CORE-3493](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3493) and provided a possible [solution](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/929) on GitHub.

**Edit:**
This change has been incorporated in version 3.10.2. However be aware that I unknowingly introduced a breaking change [issue #1293](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1293). This does not matter for new projects, but may break existing projects if variables have been used already. A workaround for that is suggested in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception about liquibase changeSets usage.

ChangeSet should be atomic and follow "one action - one changeSet" concept. It's not supposed to be some kind of "reusable function". Such approach may damage your database schema. For that reason, you don't delete old changeSets

So I suggest you write changeSets for each and every table you need to add columns to.

Also, take a look at this article: [Trimming ChangeLog Files](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/trimming_changelogs.html)

Comment: I am writing changeSets for every table (if you really look at my examble, you will see that), but just as I put common stuff into abstract super classes in JAVA, I would like to put to put the creation of those common parts of a table in a "superChangeSet", copying the same code, the same changeSet over and over is way more error prone in my book

Comment: the template does create an atomic changeSet for each table it is used in, each of those has its own ID based on the table.name property value, I see nothing that breaks the basic concept of liquibase

Comment: Yes, I get your idea, but I don't think feasible with liquibase. At least, it's beyond my expertise.